# Using HI7190 ADC, value does not match Vref?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, adc

I built the following circuit featuring the [HI7190](https://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/hi71/hi7190.pdf), 24-bit ADC, straight off the datasheet:
[image: HI7190 test circuit]

Since there is no available negative supply I built one using ICL7660, as [AN9601](https://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/an96/an9601.pdf) recommends. For VRef, as a test, I used a TL431. The actual measured VRef is 2.495V.

- If I short Vin pins, the ADC gives a reading of around **-10 to +10**, which is to be expected because of the low quality reference and circuit construction. *(This is still an impressive 6uVpp noise floor)*.
- If I put a slightly discharged AAA battery, about 1.4V, between the input pins, I get a reading of about **3 500 000**.
- If i turn the battery around, the reading is about **-3 500 000**.

In both cases, Vinhi and Vinlo are floating. The battery terminals are connected to Vinhi and Vinlo and nothing else.

The problem I have is that the ADC reading does not match the actual values between Vinhi and Vinlo. The ADC has a voltage reference of (nominal) 2.5V. The readings of 3,500,000 would mean: (3500000 * 2 * 2.5)/(2^24) = 1.0431V. This is far from the 1.4V that are at the inputs. It's about 1.345x lower.

I have noticed this error is constant across all the range. I tried several voltages at the input and they are all off by the same factor.

I have measured the reference voltage, supply voltages, ground. It's all OK.
I have even replaced the IC and the problem persists.
The ADC has calibration registers. They are a all "auto calibrated" at power up. I have also overriden them by overwriting them like the datasheet suggests, but nothing seems to change.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Try tying one side of the battery to ground.  The input instrumentation amplifier may not like floating inputs.

Comment: @JohnBirckhead how about the other input? You mean reference Vinlo and bat- to GND, and bat+ to vinhi?

Comment: As @John says each input has to be within the range of +/-3.2V with +/-5V supplies (probably a bit less headroom on the negative side in your case because of the unregulated charge pump). BTW, the reference should not affect the noise floor noticeably with inputs shorted.

Comment: Just try tying one side of the battery to VCM. It should not matter which.  (Battery terminals still connected to the inputs)

Comment: You're missing a link to the datasheet, which I added for you. Unfortunately, it does not discuss the details of the analog inputs, other than to say that the maximum leakage current is 1 nA. However, it's doubtful that they can operate without any return path for input leakage/bias currents, so tie at least one of them to Vcm, possibly through a large-value resistor (1M - 10M).

Comment: @DaveTweed I will try that then. A quick search through the datasheet shows no mention of the word "floating" so that may be a hint. Page 7 (Pin descriptions) says that VRhi should be positively referenced to vrlo, and vice versa. All that it says abot VCM is that it needs to be "halfway between avdd and avss".

Comment: Update: i have added a 1M resistor between vinlo and VCM. No effect. If i short vinlo to gnd though, the adc "hangs" if i revert the battery polarity.

Comment: Try connecting the 2.5V ref to Vinhi and connect Vinlo to ground and see what it reads

Comment: What is your series resistance on the reference?

Comment: @EE_socal if I do that it reads about 6 223 000. If I use that as the full scale value, 3 500 000 is about 1.4, which is the right value. But that doesn't make sense!

Comment: @JohnBirckhead it's a 470R resistor.

Comment: With 2.5 ref as input it should read 8 388 600. So your reading is off by a factor of 0.742 It could have something to do with the calibration registers.

Comment: @EE_socal that's what I thought, but I've tried both internal auto calibration, and manual calibration (as spec'd by te datasheet), but the result doesn't change.  
"Non-calibrated data can be obtained from the device by writing 000000 (h) to the Offset Calibration Register, 800000 (h) to the Positive Full Scale Calibration Register, and 800000 (h) to the Negative Full Scale Calibration Register. This sets the offset correction factor to 0 and the positive and negative gain slope factors to 1"
There's also an external calibration but this is not practical as it involves disconnecting inputs.

Comment: I am out of ideas, have you tried contacting Intersil?

Comment: If you have a scope, try looking at the reference input to see if there are positive spikes.

Comment: I just got an answer from Intersil support. Apparently this part needs to be calibrated in order to perform as expected. Calibrating involves setting the inputs to Vmin, 0, and Vmax externally. The datasheet gives the impression that the internal calibration procedure would be good enough (it disconnects the inputs and does -Vref, 0, +Vref automatically), but this doesn't seem to be working for me either. Time to select another part!

Comment: Take a look at Linear Tech, I think they have the best parts and support.

Comment: Yep, LT and Analog Devices are superb. Expensive though. But since I had this part in storage since 2005 when they gave me a few as samples, I decided to try them.